# SublimeLinter not working

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I installed SublimeLinter for sublime text 3. After install i add the following code in my user settings

```
 "sublimelinter": true,
        "sublimelinter_executable_map": {
            "php": "D:/xampp/xampp/php/php.exe"
        },
```

but php code not linting.
Thanks for help!

Comment: check the console, maybe one of your rules is bad

Answer (score 2):

Please read the ***entire*** [SublimeLinter documentation](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), especially the sections on installation and settings. SublimeLinter itself is only a **framework** for linters. The linters themselves are distributed as independent Sublime Text 3 plugins.

For PHP, the most popular linter is [`SublimeLinter-php`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-php), which uses `php -l` for linting. Install it via Package Control, then read through the [settings](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html) documentation for full details on how to configure the linter. I'm not sure where you got the settings you mentioned in your question, but they are incorrect. If you open `Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeLinter -> Settings-User` you'll find that most of the settings are already there. The documentation describes how to set the path to `php.exe`, and set everything else up. The initial setup process does take some time, but performed correctly you shouldn't have any issues going forward.

Comment: Your post is correct for OSX and Linux. SublimeLinter docs are totally off for Windows. At first I thought it was me, but quick googling (still) proves otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help if someone have the same problem. 
I made it work this way (Sublime Text 3):

1. Go to Preferences > Package Settings > Sublime Linter > Settings
2. Add this code on Settings-User with your php.exe path

```js
// SublimeLinter Settings - User
{
    "paths": {
        "windows": ["C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php7.2.14"]
    }
}
```

For example if you're using wamp with php7.2.14

[Take a look at the documentation site](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#adding-to-the-paths-setting)

Comment: Indeed, one has to remove the "php.exe" part and leave just the directory to get it work (on Windows at least).